# Setting title and summary automatically for custom preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I made a custom dialog preference with a custom layout in the settings activity. Here the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dip"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
            android:maxLines="4"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- ... -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Everything shows up but the title and summary that don't show any value even if they have a `@android:id`. This seems to work for some people but not for me.

I took my code from here: [layout](https://github.com/hidroh/materialistic/blob/34/app/src/main/res/layout/preference_theme.xml), [class](https://github.com/hidroh/materialistic/blob/34/app/src/main/java/io/github/hidroh/materialistic/preference/ThemePreference.java) and [xml preference](https://github.com/hidroh/materialistic/blob/34/app/src/main/res/xml/preferences.xml). If you look closely, nothing is done to link title and summary views to the xml preference file values, but they are. How? **Here I'm talking about `android:title` and `android:summary` values.**

I won't add my custom preference code, but the problem shouldn't be there. I have the 4 constructors and I use `setLayoutResource` correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the LinearLayout having no orientation. If I add `android:orientation="vertical"` everything appears correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Usually in preferences you should add "%s" in the summary

android:summary="%s"

Comment: I was unclear, I'm talking about the `android:title` and `android:summary` values not being applied to their textviews in my layout.